# Swagger documentation for a non spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi

I have a java non-springboot application (just an ear).
For document my webservices, i am looking for a java library to helps to automate the generation of API documentation. Springfox its outdate and spring-doc is just for springboot apps. What other options are there for automate documentation in non springboot apps?

Comment: https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-editor/

Comment: This _sounds_ like spring-doc might work for plain Spring MVC apps: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/2343 But if not, and you can't use Springfox, I'm not finding anything else that will do what you're asking. (We're using Springfox for our MVC app)